# Qual a diferença entre RMI e JRMP?

Tags: java, rmi

Eu só conheço o RMI...
JRMP  é só uma forma diferente de chamar o RMI ou é um outro protocolo?
No caso de JRMP ser um outro protocolo, qual a sua diferença em relação ao RMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RMI**

O [RMI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI) (*Remote Method Invocation*) é uma interface de programação que permite a execução de chamadas remotas no estilo RPC em aplicações desenvolvidas em `Java`. É uma das abordagens da plataforma Java para prover as funcionalidades de uma plataforma de objetos distribuídos. Esse sistema de objetos distribuídos faz parte do núcleo básico de Java desde a versão `JDK 1.1`, com sua API sendo especificada através do pacote `java.rmi` e seus subpacotes.

Através da utilização da arquitetura RMI, é possível que um objeto ativo em uma máquina virtual Java possa interagir com objetos de outras máquinas virtuais `Java`, independentemente da localização dessas máquinas virtuais.

**JRMP**

[JRMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Remote_Method_Protocol) (*Java Remote Method Protocol*) é o protocolo específico da tecnologia Java para olhar para cima e fazer referência a objetos remotos. É um protocolo de nível fio funcionando em um nível abaixo de RMI (RMI) e através de TCP/IP.

**Camadas de Software do Sistema RMI**

A implementação do RMI é essencialmente feita de três camadas de abstração. A camada *Stub* e *Skeleton* está abaixo dos olhos do desenvolvedor. Esta camada intercepta as chamadas de métodos feitas pelo cliente para que a variável de referência da interface redirecione essas chamadas para o serviço RMI remoto.

A próxima camada é a *Remote Reference Layer*. Esta camada sabe como interpretar e gerenciar referências feitas dos clientes para os objetos do serviço remoto. A conexão do cliente ao servidor é *Unicast* (uma-para-um).

A camada de transporte é baseada nas conexões `TCP/IP` entre as máquinas em uma rede. Usando essa arquitetura de camadas, cada uma das camadas poderia ser facilmente melhorada ou substituída sem afetar o resto do sistema. Por exemplo, a camada de transporte poderia ser substituída por uma camada que implemente conexões UDP/IP, sem afetar as camadas superiores.

Esta camada lida diretamente com a comunicação entre as várias JVM's, usando TCP/IP. É importante referir que mesmo que as JVM's sejam executadas no mesmo computador, o RMI recorre sempre à comunicação TCP/IP. Isto significa que é sempre é necessário possuir uma interface de rede funcional para se poder utilizar RMI (mesmo tendo a aplicação cliente e a aplicação servidora a executar no mesmo computador). Sobre a pilha TCP/IP o RMI possui um protocolo denominado JRMP, e que permite ultrapassar alguns obstáculos que podem surgir na comunicação de rede via TCP/IP. Por exemplo, o JRMP permite multiplexar várias ligações TCP/IP numa única ligação TCP/IP ultrapassando imposições de utilização de apenas uma ligação em alguns ambientes (ex.: certos browsers a correr Applets RMI)

**Java RMI não é exatamente um protocolo de transporte?**

Não. Java RMI é um conjunto de APIs e um modelo para objetos remotos que permite aos desenvolvedores construir facilmente aplicações distribuídas em Java. Por exemplo, usa interfaces Java normais para definir objetos remotos em uma linguagem separada como IDL. Normalmente Java RMI usa uma combinação de serialização Java e o *Java Remote Method Protocol* (JRMP) para converter a aparência normal de um método em uma invocação remota de métodos.

Com Java RMI, JRMP continuará suportando e melhorando o protocolo nativo para Java RMI.

**Que é um protocolo de transporte?**

Um protocolo de transporte define um conjunto de formatos de mensagem que permitem passar dados através de uma rede de um computador a outro. Java RMI suporta seu próprio protocolo de transporte (JRMP) e outros protocolos regulares da indústria incluindo IIOP.

Veja mais em: [Java: Remote Method Invocation](http://classroom.orange.com/pt/java-remote-method-invocation-internet-inter-orb-protocol.html)

Comment: Obrigdado pela Atenção , poderia esclarecer mais essa parte :  " É um protocolo de nível fio funcionando ..."

Comment: @PenaPintada, é tradução ao pé da letra de "wire level protocol". Em uma rede, um protocolo de fio é o mecanismo de transmissão de dados do ponto A ao ponto b. O termo é um pouco confuso, porque soa como camada 1 da rede, o que coloca fisicamente os bits "no fio". Em alguns casos, pode referir-se a camada 1; No entanto, ele geralmente se refere a camadas mais altas, incluindo Ethernet e ATM (camada 2) e ainda mais elevados camada distribuída protocolos de objetos, tais como SOAP, CORBA ou RMI.